# My player walk through walls before detecting collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, unityscript

### **When walking up to a wall from 1 unit away the player stops fine**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UqlA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMWdb.png)

### **When standing next to the wall, when player presses an arrow key towards the wall the player walks through it**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Qwe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxISy.png)

```
private bool isMoving;
public bool canMove;
private Vector2 originPos, targetPos;
public float timeToMove = 0.3f;

public Transform rayOrigin;
public float size;
public Vector2 direction;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

// assign the actions asset to this field in the inspector:
public InputActionAsset actions;

// private field to store move action reference
private InputAction moveAction;

void Awake()
{
    // find the "move" action, and keep the reference to it, for use in Update
    moveAction = actions.FindActionMap("gameplay").FindAction("move");

}

void Start()
{
    canMove = true;

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    P_Input();
}

private void P_Input()
{
    // Detect Collision
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin.position, direction, size, ~(1 << 8));

    Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin.position, direction * size, Color.green);

    // Read the move input
    Vector2 moveInput = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "obstacle")
        {
            if (moveInput == direction)
            {
                canMove = false;
            }
            else
            {
                canMove = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (canMove == true)
    {
        if (moveInput.x == -1f)
        {
            direction = moveInput;

            if (!isMoving)
            { 
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(moveInput));
            }
        }
        if (moveInput.x == 1f)
        {
            direction = moveInput;

            if (!isMoving)
            {
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(moveInput));
            }
        }
        if (moveInput.y == 1f)
        {
            direction = moveInput;

            if (!isMoving)
            {
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(moveInput));
            }
        }
        if (moveInput.y == -1f)
        {
            direction = moveInput;

            if (!isMoving)
            {
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(moveInput));
            }
        }
    }

}

private IEnumerator MovePlayer(Vector2 direction)
{
    if (canMove == true)
    {
        isMoving = true;

        float elapseTime = 0;

        originPos = transform.position;
        targetPos = originPos + direction;

        while (elapseTime < timeToMove)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(originPos, targetPos, (elapseTime / timeToMove));
            elapseTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.position = targetPos;

        isMoving = false;
    }
}

void OnEnable()
{
    actions.FindActionMap("gameplay").Enable();
}
void OnDisable()
{
    actions.FindActionMap("gameplay").Disable();
}
```

}

I created a character with a kinematic rigidbody2D and I'm trying to detect collisions with objects by using a ray-cast that changes direction depending on the user input. It works fine unless you stand right next to a wall and then walk towards it.

I figure it's because the ray-cast is too late to checking the collision when it changes directions.
I've tried using a ray-cast array to cast rays in all for directions a check the collisions with a loop but that creates a whole different set of collision malfunctions. I'm really scratching my head with this one.

Comment: What have you done besides write this code to try to figure this out?  What sites are you learning from?  Who has experienced something like this?

Comment: Because you change position rather than using rigid body you arent relying on physics so it almost certainly wont notice it collided

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code you are changing position of object without considering any physics so it will pass even collisions are detected correctly
while (elapseTime < timeToMove)
{
transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(originPos, targetPos, (elapseTime / timeToMove));
elapseTime += Time.deltaTime;
yield return null;
}

```
    transform.position = targetPos;

    isMoving = false;
```

To resolve this Either Use
Rigidbody.force and make it dynamic or if kinematic is required
use transform.translate with collision detection
You are starting coroutines multiple times
Make sure there is always one for movement.
and nature of coroutine may make collision detection and movement out of sync by one or two frames.

Comment: Thank you. now I just have to figure out how to adapt tranform.Translate